# Self value factory in TableView

Tags: java, javafx

Is there any way I can use a value factory that retrieves the own element in a `TableColumn`  in javafx? The following code illustrates better the idea:

```
class MyData {
  ...
  toString() { ... }
}

TableView<MyData> table = new TableView<>();
TableColumn<MyData, MyData> theDataColumn = new TableColumn<>("The data");
theDataColumn.setCellValueFactory(data -> data); // what is supposed to be here?
```

Comment: `data -> new SimpleObjectProperty<>(data)`? Why do you want to do this?

Comment: This way didn't work. I can't construct a `CellValueFactory` exactly this way :/ . I actually have more complex inheritance classes omitted and `MyData` is the root one. And my table has other columns, I want to do this, then the `toString` overritten by the other inherited classes would be shown in the cell.

Comment: Oh, sorry, of course it should be `data -> new SimpleObjectProperty<>(data.getValue())` If that doesn't work, create and post a simple [MCVE].

Comment: I should point out, though, that it's not good practice to rely on a `toString()` implementation for your UI. Wouldn't it be better here to define a `StringProperty` in `MyData` and allow the subclasses to set the value?

Comment: Perhaps could I define a method, say `stringfy` inside `MyData` and override it, then use `data -> new SimpleStringProperty(data.getValue().stringfy())`? Would be a better pratice? (with `TableColumn<MyData,String>`)

Comment: That's probably better, but I'd still use a property-based approach.